# What does "to give some sense of the way in which" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-structure

> But here, I want to use particular case studies to bring out the very different demands that circumstances make on the practice of diplomats.
>   I also want **to give some sense of the way in which** skilful diplomacy, as well as rashness, excessive caution, and clumsiness, can have important ramifications for the fate of nations.

Does it mean: "I want to give a meaning of the acting forms of skilful diplomacy?"

Answer (score 3):

When you encounter the collocations *give/have/get a/some sense*, what the word *sense* usually means is not "meaning" but "perception"; and the indefinite indeterminer implies a general impression rather than an exhaustive catalog or a precise definition.

> I'm getting the sense that he doesn't want me to be involved.
>   This memoir gives us a sense of what it was like to grow up in Chicago in the fifties.

*The way* is used here with the very loose meaning of "the course of events". *The way in which X happens* is more or less equivalent to *how X happens*, the events and circumstances which lead to X.

So this can be paraphrased as

> I want to give you a general impression of how skillful diplomacy can have an effect on the fate of nations.